# Entity Framework Core Issue - Update-Database Creating "User" Schemas

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been working for quite a while on a production application using .NET Core 2.0 (originally 1.0) & EF Core.

This is a Code-First designed application, so all database changes have been made via Migrations.

Up until a recent deployment, Update-Database would make the changes correctly - however, recently it has been creating new schemas each time a model is added (instead of adding to the dbo schema like normal).

Example:

```
New Class Model: Test.cs
Table created in Database: DOMAIN\CurrentUser.Test
```

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

I suppose I can dig deep into the migrationBuilder to figure out how it is making Schema decisions, but seems like something simple must have changed to change the behavior.

"DOMAIN\CurrentUser" has dbo rights on the server in question.

Comment: Share us the generated migrations related with `Test` model. Is there any `DOMAIN\CurrentUser` in the migration file? Check the database whether you change the default schema in database.

Comment: I checked through the SQL in the Migration file already - nothing related to schemas in there. I'll try out your answer below though tonight or tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

For changing schema from `EF Core`, try to configure with `builder.HasDefaultSchema("newschema");` or `builder.Entity<User>().ToTable`.

For changing the schema for all tables.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("newschema");
    }
}
```

For chaning the schema for specific table.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User", "newSchema");
    }
}
```